# Error build android apk while using facebook plugins in ionic3

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, ionic3

The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_6jy1i81bonl94r9ffpxyja5iq.run(E:\avtar\All Project Latest code\MindfulScholar\platforms\android\build.gradle:141)
The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.

Comment: getting these error

Comment: did you google the issue at all? https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/issues/470